# Rails rabl condition for class variable in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rabl

In controller i have such code:

```
    @bank_exchangers = ExchangerList.find(:all, :conditions => {:bank_id => params[:id]})
    @currency_list = CurrencyList.all
    @currencies = []
    @currency_list.each do |c|
      @currencies << CurrencyValue.find(:all, :conditions => {:currency_list_id => c.id}, :order => :updated_at)
    end
    @currencies.flatten!
```

and i have such models:

```
class CurrencyList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :country, :name
  has_many :currency_values
end


class CurrencyValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :currency_list_id, :direction_of_exchange_id, :value
  belongs_to :currency_list
  belongs_to :exchanger_list
end


class ExchangerList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :bank_id, :exchanger_type_id, :latitude, :location_id, :longitude, :name
  has_many :currency_values
end
```

i need to display for each ExchangerList it's CurrencyValue with some conditions, as i provided below... But main trouble is with rabl output:

i have such code:

```
collection @bank_exchangers, :root => "bank_exchangers", :object_root => false
attributes :id, :name, :address, :location_id, :latitude, :longitude, :exchanger_type_id
child @currencies do 
  attribute :value 
end
```

as you can see, here for each @bank_exchangers i create node with it's @currencies... But i need to display node only for this @bank_exchangers iterator, if i would write in controller i would write something like:

```
@currencies << CurrencyValue.find(:all, :conditions => {:currency_list_id => c.id, :exchanger_list_id => param}, :order => :updated_at)
```

How to set something like this in view?

Becouse now my output is like:

```
{"bank_exchangers":[{"id":3,"name":"Банк *** ЦБУ №1","address":"г. Минск, ул. Московская, 13","location_id":8,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"exchanger_type_id":1,"location_name":"Минск","exchanger_type_name":"normal","currency_values":[{"currency_value":{"value":8620.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8620.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8700.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8700.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8620.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8700.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":11500.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":11100.0}}]},{"id":4,"name":"Банк ***","address":"г. Минск, Мясникова, 32","location_id":8,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"exchanger_type_id":1,"location_name":"Минск","exchanger_type_name":"normal","currency_values":[{"currency_value":{"value":8620.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8620.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8700.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8700.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8620.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":8700.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":11500.0}},{"currency_value":{"value":11100.0}}]}]}
```

as you can see, for each bank_exchangers  i create node with all currency_values data, but i need to put for each bank_exchangers in node only  currency_values  for this bank_exchangers parent....

How could i do this?

Sorry if something is not clear... i'm new...

**Just how to set for my child @currencies in view some condition?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the relation between ExchangerList and CurrencyValues:

```
child :currency_values do
  attribute :value
end
```

If you have conditions, you can include these using a lambda:
if => lambda { |child| child.something? })

```
child(:currency_values, if => lambda { |currency_value| currency_value.something? }) do
  attribute :value
end
```

You may also want to define a view for just the one ExchangerList object (i.e. show):

```
object @bank_exchanger, :object_root => false
attributes :id, :name, :address, :location_id, :latitude, :longitude, :exchanger_type_id

child(:currency_values, if => lambda { |currency_value| currency_value.something? }) do
  attribute :value
end
```

Then simply have the collection extend this:

```
collection @bank_exchangers, :root => "bank_exchangers", :object_root => false
extends 'bank_exchangers/show'
```

Alternatively, if you add a 'currencies' method to to the ExchangerList model, you can call the method directly as an attribute via RABL. Some test code I wrote:

```
def test
  test_array = []
  1.upto(3) do |i|
    test_array << {qty: i, px: 2*i}
  end
  return test_array
end
```

You can then simply call this as an attribute:

```
object @object
attribute :test
```

This results in the following JSON, which I believe is similar to the format you are trying to achieve:

```
test: [
  {
    qty: 1,
    px: 2
  },
  {
    qty: 2,
    px: 4
  },
  {
    qty: 3,
    px: 6
  }
],
```

Comment: hem, but how with my code? just add one more condition? becouse lambdas are not good here...

Comment: as you see i have iterator in method

Comment: how to do this in ruby loops? like each

Comment: If you can write the iterator as a method on the ExchangeList model, you can call the method directly as an attribute via RABL. I'll add a code example above.

Comment: i need it for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001256/rails-rabl-collection-with-if-statement

Comment: please take a look at my second question.... Rails rabl collection with if statement

Comment: didn't you know? why you are ingoring me?

Comment: It seems to me that the two examples provided are both generic and detailed enough to let you figure out your RABL question. I'm not clear on what exactly is giving you the trouble. CurrencyValue already belongs to ExchangerList, so some_exchanger_list.currency_values will already filter to just the ones belonging to that one. You can write additional conditions inside the child node, as a method, or using a labmda to filter this further.

Comment: how to write this condition? syntax?   also in first line i have collection.... how to get on each iteration collection.id?

Comment: hem, tell me please how can i access in my code to collection @bank_exchangers  bank's id?